# Access by same Community user to Two Communities

Tags: community, single-sign-on, login

I have two communities and a user (profile) which has access to both communities.
I would like to allow them to login once and when they want to transfer to the other community just click a link or a button and be redirected to the other community without the need to re log in.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each community represents its own security context. That is, community B doesn't automagically "trust" community A in terms of user logging in even if the same user is a member of both communities. To go from one to the other without re-authentication, you will need to implement single sign-on via SAML or OpenID Connect.

With SAML, your community A will be the identity provider and community B will be the service provider. You will need to create a connected app for community B to make it a SAML service provider. To make community A into an identity provider you need to turn on identity provider at the org level; it will automatically include all communities.

See the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_auth_configure_saml.htm&type=5) and Trailhead tutorial(s) ([connected apps](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/connected-app-basics), [identity](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_basics)) for more details.

Comment: How would that impact licenses? If a member is a part of multiple communities does that member have multiple salesforce users with community license?

Comment: @Tejas Ghalsasi The license is on a per-user basis. 1 license is consumed for a given user regardless of how many communities they visit or belong to